# Any ubuntu drivers for wireless adapter Trendnet TBW-108UB?

Tags: drivers, wireless, usb, adapter

I been looking something to get work the adapter from trendnet TBW-108UB in ubuntu, the integrated wlan is not working anymore so i bought the trendnet adapter wifi and bluetooth, it seams that bluetooth is working, but wifi is not recognized by the os. It works well with Windows, but I also use Ubuntu pls help.

Link to the official site of the adapter
https://www.trendnet.com/support/support-detail.asp?prod=190_TBW-108UB

```
$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 20f4:108a TRENDnet <---this is the adapter 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Ive tried this one:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide
but nm-tool: not found

```
sudo lshw -C network 
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       logical name: enp7s0
       version: 07
       serial: 14:18:77:c3:bc:a9
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8106e-1_0.0.1 06/29/12 ip=192.168.50.241 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:43 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:a9000000-a9000fff memory:c0000000-c0003fff
```

as you can see with lshw -C network is just showing the ethernet adapter, the trendnet is not there.

I have also tried to in software and updates -> additional drivers
to install propietary drivers: no additional drivers available.

Comment: Please run `lsusb`  with the adapter connected. Then [edit] the question and post the line pertaining to the adapter.

Comment: How is it recognized?  (prior comment, and did you try any steps found in the documentation, if so tell us what you found with regards chipset etc) - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have modified the lwfinger rtl8723bu so that it should support your device, do

```
sudo apt install git build-essential dkms
git clone https://github.com/jeremyb31/rtl8723bu.git
sudo dkms add ./rtl8723bu
sudo dkms install rtl8723bu/4.3.6.11_12942.20141204_BTCOEX20140507-4E40
```

Secure Boot will need to be disabled on UEFI systems, you can check Secure Boot status in terminal with `mokutil --sb-state`

Reboot

Comment: Thank you so much, this works.  // to show the modules installed with dkms
dkms status

    // to remove the installed module
    sudo dkms remove rtl8723bu/4.3.6.11_12942.20141204_BTCOEX20140507-4E40 --all

Comment: Good to hear, there are a few different places the USB ID could be added in lwfingers source code, I must have got it correct

Comment: It works just take in mind, it can't connect to 802.11n connections just legacy b g, I think, and you need to restart ubuntu to change to another network or if gets disconected. but is better than nothing xD.

Comment: It seems that is an issue with the source code lwfinger has from Realtek, https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8723bu/issues/92

Answer (score 0):

You can find a driver info page [here](https://wikidevi.com/wiki/TRENDnet_TBW-108UB_V1). They call out it requiring a driver for a Realtek RTL8723BU chip set.

Drivers can be found [here](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8723bu) and possibly [here](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/rtl819x).

Comment: Thank you, but it didn't work. but thanks for the info, so now i know is a realtek.